# How should I escape a string for use in a filename in vimscript

Tags: vim

I'm working on a vim plugin and I need to accept a string from the user and use it as part of a filename. How should I escape the string?

[`fnameescape()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#fnameescape%28%29) looked promising, but upon testing, it did not escape slashes.

**Edit**: Purpose: I'm working on a plugin that will allow me to have .vimrc files which are specific to the git repo I happen to be working in. It looks at the hash of the first commit and uses that as a unique id to locate the file to source. I also want those files to have a human readable component, so I am prompting the user for that part of the filename. I want to make sure they don't accidentally enter characters that will cause the file creation/retrieval to fail.

Comment: seems to escape slashes to me. The slashes must be escaped by the user though to stop vim interpreting them as slashes for something else (such as `\n` or `\r`). How are you using the function?

Comment: @FDinoff If I issue `:echo fnameescape('test/test')` I get: `test/test` back. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `/` can not be a filename (in linux. I can't say anything about windows). I don't think its possible to escape that that slash at all. It will always be interpreted as a path separator. You can escape ``\`` though

Comment: Then perhaps I need a function to strip path separators? presumably the function would need to be OS dependant.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do maybe someone can suggest the something for you to do. (It sounds like you want to reject invalid characters from strings right?)

Comment: You could do something like this to remove non `isfname` and slash characters. `substitute('filename string', \v%(\f@!|/@=.)+', '' ,'g')` and then you can file name escape whats left if you want.

Comment: @FDinoff I've added brief description of why (I think) I need this. I'll give your other suggestion a try, but I was hoping for a OS aware solution.